# Selenium - wait until synchronisation is done

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-ide, acceptance-testing

I have an application that will sycnhronize data into the localstorage after logging in. See the following:

[image]

**Console:**

[image]

But when I run the selenium test it results in an error because the following screen isn't loaded yet. **The one API call can take longer than the other** (can always be different). How can I make sure the selenium test waits until all synchronization done?

Comment: By default Selenium waits for an element to appear before raising an exception. You can increase time out.

Comment: You should ask yourself how a user would know that the synchronization is done and then write the test accordingly. For instance, you could wait for the count of visible spinners to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think following should work, if this element is present but not visible after everything is loading. Else you need to change the condition.

I am not sure which language you are using, however you can convert the code to language of your choice.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[conatains(text(),'Bezig')]")))
```

Comment: I'm using the Selenium IDE plugin in firefox. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @nielsv i don't think so but then I don't have any experience with latest version of IDE.